# SQL: select values in table A which are not in table B (and the other way around)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a hypothetical Census information by areas (Districts) collected in two different years:

**Year 1 Table**

```
District | Name
----------------
1        | Paul
1        | John
2        | Max
2        | Aaron
3        | Michael
```

**Year 2 Table**

```
District | Name
1        | Paul
1        | John
1        | Michael
3        | Michael
```

I'd like two queries:

**Query 1:** List new people by District. Should return Michael in District 1

**Query 2:** List missed people by District. Should return Max and Aaron in District 2

Comment: You should tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I have added SQL-Server in the tag

Comment: Brilliant, all in one query!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this using `union all` and aggregation.  The following query returns the name/district combinations that appear only in one year, along with the specific year:

```
select district, name, min(yyyy)
from ((select 1 as yyyy, district, name from table1) union all
      (select 2, district, name from table2)
     ) tt
group by district, name
having count(distinct yyyy) = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Query 1 : List new people by District. Should return Michael in District 1**

```
SELECT        Name, District
FROM            year2
WHERE        (Name NOT IN
                             (SELECT        Name
                               FROM            year1
                               WHERE        (District = year2.District)))
GROUP BY Name, District
```

**Query 2: List missed people by District. Should return Max and Aaron in District 2**

```
SELECT        Name, District
FROM            year1
WHERE        (Name NOT IN
                             (SELECT        Name
                               FROM            year2
                               WHERE        (District = District)))
GROUP BY Name, District
```

If further you need combined result just use `union all`